# Why does my Ktor unit test throw an exception instead of returning a response with a 500 status code?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have an exception that is being thrown in my routing plugin and when running the app, the endpoint correctly returns a 500 status code.

I would like to write a unit test to emulate this behavior, but the test keeps throwing an exception, instead of returning the response with a 500.  How can I fix this?

Below is my test.  When I run it, it gives me an exception, instead of returning a response.

```
    @Test
    fun genericExceptionShouldRespondWithInternalServerError() = testApplication {
        //given
        val expectedHttpStatus = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
        val expectedResponseText = "Internal Server Error"
        application {
            install(StatusPages) {
                status(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { call, status ->
                    call.respondText(text = "Internal Server Error", status = status)
                }
            }
            routing {
                get("/servererror") {
                    throw Exception("Generic Exception")
                }
            }
        }

        //when
        val response = client.get("/servererror")

        //then
        assertEquals(expectedHttpStatus, response.status)
        assertEquals(expectedResponseText, response.bodyAsText())
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration [`status`](https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html#status) in Status pages is for configuring a response to a status code value. Since you are throwing exceptions you will have to use [`exceptions`](https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html#exceptions) configuration option.

So if you want the unit test to pass, you can change the code to the following to include exception configuration in status pages:

```
install(StatusPages) {
        exception<Exception> { call, cause ->
            call.respondText(text = "Internal Server Error", status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  That does make my unit test pass, but it causes my CallFailed hook to stop being called, which isn't ideal.